# Linearly independent functions on 2D

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-analysis

Let $ \quad f_k, \quad 0 \leq k \leq 4,$ be set of 5 different functions such that
$$\frac{\partial f_{k}}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial f_{k+1}}{\partial x_2}= 0, \quad 0 \leq k \leq 3.$$

Define $(Df)_k = \frac{\partial f_{k+1}}{\partial x_1} - \frac{\partial f_{k}}{\partial x_2}, \quad 0 \leq k \leq 3.$

How can I show that
$(Df)_0 = 3(Df)_2$ and $(Df)_3 = 3(Df)_1.$

Thank you.

Comment: Let $f_i=(-1)^i\frac{\partial^4 F}{\partial x_1^{4-i}\partial x_2^{i}}$, where $F \in \mathcal{C}^5$ (if $f_i$ are smooth enough this is the only solution by building potential and finding relationship between them). Then, $f_i$ satisfy the required condition. Also, notice that in that case $(Df)_k = (-i)^{k+1}\frac{\partial^3 \Delta F}{\partial x_1^{3-k}\partial x_2^{k}}$

Comment: This is not clear to me